# Android Studio closes when wanting to open a layout

Tags: android-studio

I installed the latest version of Android Studio on Windows 10 and when trying to open a layout, Android Studio closes completely. I have looked for a solution on the internet but could not find a solution. Every time it fails I get a text error report, I don't know how to interpret all this information, could you be so kind to help me solve this?

Text error report

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x00007ff8bd2039af, pid=3032, tid=3188 JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.10) (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189) Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.10+0-b96-7249189, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64) Problematic frame: C [libandroid_runtime.dll+0xb39af]

No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit: https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code. See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d)

It's like it's something to do with memory, but I can't figure it out.

CAPTURE OF A FEW SECONDS BEFORE CLOSING COMPLETELY ANDROID STUDIO
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz0NO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this issue and also posted it here earlier but noone seemed to know how to fix it or why it happends and neither do I and still dont.

I fixed it by downloading older/newer version of android studio.
You are probbably using Android Studio Arctic Fox since it's the first one that you get when you go on Android Studio site and click download.

Next to download button you will se download archives go there and download some other version.
Personally I downloaded Bumblebee Cannary channel and it works great.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I actually solved it as you indicated. The problem is that it runs out of memory, the new version of android studio consumes much more ram memory than the previous versions.